# How to sort string array by length?

Tags: arrays, sorting, delphi, delphi-xe2

So, I want to sort array of strings by length (longer strings goes first) and if length is the same, then sort alphabetically. This is what is got so far:

```
uses
  System.Generics.Defaults
  , System.Types
  , System.Generics.Collections
  ;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  _SortMe: TStringDynArray;
begin
  _SortMe := TStringDynArray.Create('abc', 'zwq', 'Long', 'longer');

  TArray.Sort<string>(_SortMe, TDelegatedComparer<string>.Construct(
    function(const Left, Right: string): Integer
    begin
      Result := CompareText(Left, Right);
    end));
end;
```

Expected result: longer, Long, abc, zwq

Comment: Where in your code do you compare lengths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjusting your anonymous function:

```
function(const Left, Right: string): Integer
    begin
      //Compare by Length, reversed as longest shall come first
      Result := CompareValue(Right.Length, Left.Length);
      if Result = EqualsValue then
        Result := CompareText(Left, Right);
    end));
```

You'll need to add System.Math and System.SysUtils to your uses.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used a `TStringList` for this...

Any way, just customize the comparison function:

```
  TArray.Sort<string>(_SortMe, TDelegatedComparer<string>.Construct(
    function(const Left, Right: string): Integer
    begin
      Result := length(Right) - length(Left); // compare by decreasing length
      if Result = 0 then
        Result := CompareText(Left, Right);  // compare alphabetically
    end));
```